# Making Alternative Languages For a ASP.NET WebSite

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web

I was using a website's source codes for my summer project. The website language that i using is English. I want to translate it to Turkish. I found a language pack on internet.I am using it , And there is codes like that:

```
        <LocaleResource Name="reviews.seeafterapproving">
            <Value>Some Turkish correspondings</Value>
        </LocaleResource>

        <LocaleResource Name="reviews.submitbutton">
            <Value>Some Turkish correspondings</Value>
        </LocaleResource>
        <LocaleResource Name="reviews.successfullyadded">

            <Value>Some Turkish correspondings</Value>
          </LocaleResource>
```

Now there is some missing part in the language pack that i found. I want to fix it. But i don't know which code corresponds to a any "LocaleResource Name". For example lets say there is ;

```
<LocaleResource Name="reviews.write">
        <Value></Value>
    </LocaleResource>
```

And i want to translate that "reviews.write" to Turkish. So how can i find what does reviews.write stand for? In visual studio , is there a way to find reviews.write's English representative?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a resource file for each language you want to support.

For example: Create two resource files, one for english and the other for turkish. Now these can be named `locale-en.resx` and `locale-tk.resx`. In these files you create variables like `reviews.write` and translate them to the specified language. The last thing you need to do is to tell `LocaleResource` which file to use.

[See also](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization)